# Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, exception, class, casting

why do i get this exception?

Map myHash = null
myHash = (HashMap)Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

If i try to use this hashmap, i get java.lang.ClassCastException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Collections.synchronizedMap() does not return a HashMap.

Correct way should be:

Map mySyncedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

(or any other map instead of HashMap)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Collections.synchronizedMap` does not return a `HashMap`.

It returns some other kind of `Map` (the type of which you should not need to know), that wraps your `HashMap`.

You have to use the `Map` interface  instead of `HashMap`.